# MSIE8 compatibility mode not rendering dynamically created table

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

A bit weird...  ...if running in IE8 quirks mode or in compatibility view mode, the table added by the following code doesn't render. Can anyone tell me why, because it is not obvious to me..?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
function AddTable()
{
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(row);
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.innerHTML='abc';
  row.appendChild(cell);
  var divContainer = document.getElementById('divContainer');
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='divContainer'>
</div>
<input type='button' value='add table' onclick='javascript:AddTable()' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting. If you add a 
 alert(divContainer.outerHTML); 
after the appendChild, you'll see that your DOM has been updated, but nothing renders.

Comment: Works in standards mode; someone proposed a workaround for quirks here: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread22162.html

Comment: Yes, that is the weird thing; the DOM has been updated but nothing renders. I tried playing around with various CSS attributes to see if that could somehow force it to render something but so far no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the workaround. I guess I'll just add a check if it is running in IE, and then I'll do the divContainer.innerHTML = divContainer.innerHTML trick....

Comment: (reason for bounty: the above workaround (from EricLaw) works fine, but I still wonder if this is a bug or by-design and if so why... ...so I figured a bounty would be in place...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft has a page that may illuminate what's going on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998(VS.85).aspx#TOM_Create

For dynamically building tables they advocate the "Table Object Model", which uses methods like `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` to do the job you're doing with the DOM methods`createElement()` and `appendChild()`.  It's also OK if you use the DOM methods, but *"Internet Explorer requires that you create a tBody element and insert it into the table when using the DOM. Since you are manipulating the document tree directly, Internet Explorer does not create the tBody, which is automatically implied when using HTML."*

The table object model works in the couple of browsers I tested it in (Chrome and Firefox on the Mac), so it may not be a bad idea to  familiarize yourself with it.  Or if you want to stick with the DOM methods, add the `tBody` element, because IE requires it.

If you add the following code to the end of your `AddTable()` method you'll see how the two compare (mainly, the second table will have a `tBody` in it).  And it will render in IE8.

```
 // now the Table Object Model way
  table = document.createElement('table');
  row = table.insertRow(-1) ;
  cell = row.insertCell(-1) ;
  cell.innerHTML='def';
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a tbody element

Instead of

```
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(row);
```

do

```
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  tbody.appendChild(row);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, yes, that makes it render the table, but has some interesting effects on how it is rendered... Not sure why yet, will see what I can find.